# More efficient way for scaling phonegap iphone application's UI?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova, canvas

I am using javascript to do this. And I was wondering if there was a 'prettier' way to do this?

Here is my way:

**I find the width and height of screen in use:**

```
var x = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var y = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
```

**I find the ratio between the canvas and screen:**

```
var Xf = (x / a_canvas.width);
var Yf = (y / a_canvas.height);
```

**Then i use this function after wards to scale the canvas:**

```
function resize_canvas() {
    if (a_canvas.width < x) {
        a_canvas.width = x;
    }
    if (a_canvas.height < y) {
        a_canvas.height = y;
    }
}
resize_canvas();
```

After this is draw my code and functions, I multiply every single coordinates with Xf or Yf, depending on if it's x and y axis.

My full code is here:
https://github.com/GunZi200/Memory-Colour/blob/master/test.js

If you guys know of a better way? Please let me know!

Comment: don't scale using javascript, use responsive web design

Comment: @jcesarmobile got any links with reading material for that?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't look at the code before, I don't think responsive web design works for canvas

Comment: Yeah that is what i thought :(